# Confusion about applying rule of inference for set theory

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic

Why we can apply rule of inference for set theory even we don't know the truth value of proposition,as the book mentioned that if the premise is false,after applying the rule of inference,the conseqence may not to be true.

For example,
we need to prove that A⋂B⊆A,but we don't know the truth value of set,since it can be the empty set.

$$A⋂B $$

$$x∈A∧x∈B (\text {logic form: } p∧q)$$

$$x∈A$$

(we  apply rule of inference: simplification)

$$A⋂B ⊆A$$

i am wonder that why we can apply rule of inference even we don't know the truth value of premise.

Another example, Dad is sleeping and mum is hunting,lets p be  dad is sleeping and q be mum is hunting.

$$p∧q$$
$$p$$

Then we can get the right consequnce that Dad is sleeping,because we know the premise is true.

Comment: Sets don't inherently have truth values: they can be assigned to truth values by a statement.

Comment: A *set* has **no** truth value: it is an object. A *statement* about sets (in the context of a specified theory about sets) has a truth value. $A \cap B \subseteq A$ is a *statement* asserting that "the set resulting from the intersection of two sets $A$ and $B$ is a subset of set $B$".

Comment: Thanks.For exanple,we have two statement,lets p be "x is a element that belong to set A" and q be"x is a element that belong to set B".we need to prove:A⋂B⊆A,then we can have p∧q,However,we don't  know the truth value of p and q, how can we apply  rule of inference to that

Comment: But what if in fact that x is not the element of A or A is a empty set,does simplification ensure that we can get the correct consequence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A set has no truth value: it is a (mathematical) object.

Syntactically, $A \cap B$  is a *term*, i.e. a "name" of a set (names have reference but not truth value).

A *statement* about sets (in the context of a specified theory about sets) has a truth value.

$A \cap B \subseteq A$ is a statement asserting that "the set resulting from the intersection of two sets $A$ and $B$ is a subset of set $A$".

The statement to which we have to apply the rules of inference is "$x \in A \cap B$" (it is a statement because has the form: "name-Relation-name", like e.g. "John is son of Peter").

The proof works this way: "$x$ is element of $A \cap B$" is our starting point.

By definition of "intersection of sets" ($\cap$) we have that: "$x$ is element of $A$ **and** $x$ is element of $B$".

Using [Simplification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_elimination) we get:

> "$x$ is element of $A$".

In symbols:

1) $x \in A \cap B$ --- premise: $x$ is an element whatever

2) $(x \in A) \land (x \in B)$ --- from 1) unwinding the definition of [set intersection ($\cap$)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory))

3) $x \in A$ --- from 2) by Simplification

4) $(x \in A \cap B) \to (x \in A)$ --- from 1) and 4) by [Conditional Proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_proof)

5) $\forall x \ [(x \in A \cap B) \to (x \in A)]$ --- from 4) by [Universal Generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization)

> 6) $(A \cap B) \subseteq A$ --- from 5) using the definition of [set inclusion ($\subseteq$)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset).

---

What happens if $A$ is the emptyset ?

The proof still holds, in a simplified form.

We can jump directly to step 4): if $A= \emptyset$, then $x \in (A \cap B)$ is False and thus the *conditional* $(x \in A \cap B) \to (x \in A)$ is True (because: $\text F \to \text F$ is $\text T$).

Thus, either $A$ is empty, and thus proceed as above, or $A$ is not empty, and thus pick an element $x$ whatever in it (for sure there is one) and use the full proof above.

Comment: This is amazing and tie the concept of rule of inference for quantififed statement with set theory proof,thanks.

Comment: @MolyHoly - you are welcome :-)

Comment: This "general mechanism" works for **every** mathematical proof... The real difficulty is that "standard" math proofs needs a lot of definitions and previous results used as lemma; trying to "unwind" them into elementary inferential steps can be discouraging, but trying to do it in some simple cases can give enough confidence that formalization can always be performed.